# What are the f and i parameters passed to callback of forEach?

Tags: javascript, foreach

What does the 'i' and 'f' mean in this code? and how is it defined + how does the code know that its the file name and amount of files?

```
if(err) console.log(err);

let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js")
if(jsfile.length <= 0){
    console.log("couldn't find commands.");
    return;
}

jsfile.forEach((f, i) =>{
    let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
    console.log(`${i} commands have loaded!`);
    bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
});
```

Comment: its being edited, i don't know how i forgot the code haha

Comment: What is `jsfile` then?

Comment: `f` & `i` they are just argument of the array `forEach`function.Google for array forEach you will know it

Answer (score -1):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) iterates items of `jsfiles` variable - which is an array generated by filtering the `files`. `f` is the item in the array, and `i` is the index of `f` in the collection.

You can read more about [`Array.prototype.forEach` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and about [`Array.prototype.filter` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

---

To give you an example about usage of `forEach`, consider that `items` in snippet below is an array. Notice the parameters `item` and `index` which correspond to actual item, and its index in the array:

```js
var items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];

items.forEach((item, index) => {
  console.log(item, "#", index);
});
```

Comment: how is jsfile defined as an array?

Comment: `let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js")`

Comment: so where in the let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js") make it an array? i thought arrays used square brackets? []

Comment: @TimothyChell Avoid chameleon question, i.e., avoid editing the question to ask more "questions". It invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @TimothyChell `files` must be an array. When you `filter` over it, the result is still an array. Sure, at some point the array might have been defined using square brackets, but that's not required. As as example consider `var x = Object.keys({})`. So the `files` array might have been generated elsewhere by other method as well.